# fatal error: 'boost/version.hpp' file not found

Tags: boost

#include <boost/version.hpp>   There is no error here, but there is an error in the run code.

vscode normal use boost.
The package paths are referenced inside the configuration file.
The development environment is macOS 14.1 (23B2073)  m3pro